# Setting an attribute from a parents attribute

Tags: jquery, hash, parent

I have this HTML and i am trying to convert the href from photo.php to #photo etc for each

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="home" class="tab_selected"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="music"><a href="music.php">Music</a></li>
    <li id="video"><a href="video.php">Video</a></li>
    <li id="photo"><a href="photo.php">Photo</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have been trying something like this:

```
$('#menu li a').attr('href', "#"+$(this).parent().attr('id'));
```

But the href always comes out undefined.

I am storing the hash in the li#id but if i could not do this it would be even better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this)` does not refer to the object you think it refers to.

With `.attr` you can use a function as a second argument to compute new attribute values for each matched element, like this:

```
// i == index, val == value of href at index i
$('#menu li a').attr('href', function(i, val) {
    return '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```

In the above example, `this` refers to the correct context (the currently iterated anchor element).

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/v5LjU/)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know jQuery supported that. +1

Answer (score 1):

All jQuery

```
$('#menu li a').each(function () {
    var a = $(this);
    a.attr('href', "#" + a.parent().attr('id');
});
```

Part jQuery

```
$('#menu li a').each(function () {
    this.href = "#" + $(this).parent()[0].id;
});
```

Less Part jQuery

```
$('#menu li a').each(function () {
    this.href = "#" + this.parentNode.id;
});
```

Take your pick :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` doesnt holds the wrong value (it refers to any wrapping context there may be), because you're not in the proper context. Look at either of the (currently) 3 other answers to see how to get around this issue ([hint, you want to use each](http://api.jquery.com/each/))

Comment: More precisely, `this` probably refers to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu li a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('href', "#"+$this.parent().attr('id'));
});
```